# How to sort list with Comparator and multiple conditions while using methods with args as sort key?

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparison

I have an unsorted list of objects:

```
List<Object> unsortedList = {objB, objB, objC, objA, objD, objA, ...}
```

My goal is to get a sorted list based on multiple conditions that looks something like this:

```
List<Object> sortedList = {objA, objA, objB, objC, objD, ...}
```

I know I could use a couple of different methods, for example Comparator:

```
Collections.sort(unsortedList, Comparator.comparing(Object::isAttributeA)
.thenComparing(Object::isAttributeB))
.thenComparing(Object::isAttributeC))...
```

However, the methods "isAttribute*" take in arguments/parameters related to the object at hand.

The needed logic in (not so pretty) for loop form looks as such:

```
for(Object obj : unsortedList){
  if(obj.isAttributeA(obj)){
    sortedList.add(obj);
  }
}
for(Object obj : unsortedList){
  if(obj.isAttributeB(obj.getField())){
    sortedList.add(obj);
  }
}
for(Object obj : unsortedList){
  if(obj.isAttributeC(obj.getAnotherField())){
    sortedList.add(obj);
  }
}
```

Is there a better or more "elegant" way to iterate through a list of objects and sort it based on multiple conditions with objects satisfying the next condition being placed after those that satisfied the previous condition?

EDIT:
The goal is to divide the unsorted list using some conditions into subgroups to assign priority for another method. In other words, there is another method that will be using this sorted list of objects to perform an action on each of the objects that has to be done in a certain order to avoid further problems.

Comment: Maybe, but the problem description is a bit too vague to answer.  Also, this may be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) but we can't tell.  You'll need to provide a small but concrete example that demonstrates what you're trying to do.  Critically, the fact that your predicates depend on arguments in addition to the objects' internal states means that you'll likely be breaking the contract for comparisons, since the results don't depend solely on the objectsand could change over time.  That's code-smell, which leads to the XY problem possibility.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm a little confused, because the problem makes perfect sense to me, and it doesn't look like it breaks the comparison contract?  Comparing mutable objects is and always has been fine, as long as you don't put them in a set.

Comment: Edited the original question to try to provide some more context. This shouldn't break any comparison contracts

Comment: The for loop logic is exactly the logic I need but it is not the prettiest solution so I am just asking for suggestions on how to improve it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is actually something like

```
private static <T> int firstSatisfying(List<Predicate<T>> predicates, T t) {
  for (int i = 0; i < predicates.size(); i++) {
    if (predicates.get(i).test(t)) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return predicates.size();
}
static final List<Predicate<Foo>> predicates = Arrays.asList(
  Foo::isAttributeA, Foo::isAttributeB, ...);
Collections.sort(
  unsortedList,
  Comparator.comparingInt(t -> firstSatisfying(predicates, t)));
```

...if you want to sort the elements by the first matching condition, in some order of the conditions.  This isn't the most efficient possible implementation, but it sounds like you only have a few conditions which are cheap to check, in which case this will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a comparator that is not a method reference.

```
List<YourObject> sortedList = unsortedList.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing((YourObject obj) -> obj.isAttributeA(obj))
        .thenComparing(obj -> obj.isAttributeB(obj.getField()))
        .thenComparing(obj -> obj.isAttributeC(obj.getAnotherField())))
    .toList();
```